# Magento1 to Magento2 Configurable product issue

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, migration, simple-product, associate-products

I have import **Magento1** to **Magento2** Configurable product but Configurable product fronted out of stock display and not show associated simple product.

Associated simple product also qty.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Have your reindex in magento2?

Comment: yes i am reindex also